# Why do floated siblings sit side by side?

Tags: html, css

```css
ul {
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<ul id = "done">
  <li>Laundry</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Garbage Take Out</li>
</ul>
```

Why is it that floating ul elements to the left as a rule makes my two ul elements sit side by side in the browser?  My thinking was that since one is under the other, this would result in the first appearing above the second, both floated to the left.  Can you please clear up my understanding?

Comment: Because they  are each in their own `ul`, and both `ul`s are floating. If you want them to be under each other, then they should be in the same `ul`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood [floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or
>   "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be
>   prohibited from doing so by the 'clear' property).

If you don't want this behavior, don't use floats or use [`clear`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-clear).

> This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may *not*
>   be adjacent to an earlier floating box.

For example, set it to `left` or `both` on the second element

```css
#done + ul {
  clear: left;
}
```

```css
ul {
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
#done + ul {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="done">
  <li>Laundry</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Garbage Take Out</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your use case to be done, the html code will be like,

```
<div style="float:left">
<ul id = "done">
        <li>Laundry</li>
     </ul>
     <ul>
        <li>Garbage Take Out</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

and remove the `float:left` from the css for the `ul` element

Answer (score 0):

Your width is only 40% so 2 ul will fit side by side as take up approx 80% (but not exactly 80% because of needing to normalize or reset css and box size).
Floating only allows elements to be naturally aligned to a left side and gives space on the page by taking things out of flow.
If you clear floats with

```
clear:left
```

then they will stack vertically.
Correct use of clear fixes will help out here.
Try here this found here:- https://web-design-weekly.com/snippets/sass-clearfix-mixin/

```
 @mixin clearfix() {
    &:before,
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
    }
    &:after {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```